# Foreground Extraction

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, background-subtraction, background-foreground, occlusion

I am doing some work regarding tracking a person, I am using this [dataset](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Elabimage/Dataset/). I am trying right now to extract foreground using background subtraction method i.e. [Mean Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_subtraction)

My background is like

[image: Background]

and if I try to subtract my current frame like this

[image]

so after subtraction I am getting image like this

[image]

and after thresholding of *0.15* or *38*

I get this mask

[image]

So if you notice this mask, it is splitting this foreground in to two pieces because of occlusion of person and chair. I dont know how to solve this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which solution is work for you? I'm encountering the same problem here.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a perfect solution, but maybe it will be enough for you - on mask image find all contours, join them(usually contours are represented as vectors of points so put all contours into one vector) and then find the convex hull of connected contour (if you are using opencv - use convexHull function http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html).

Comment: Can I get more explanations? What is actually the contours? How if I'm using Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

It's also not a perfect solution. Please reduce the number of frames to create background image in background subtraction method  it may help you. Or initialize the  background subtraction structure frequently.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to do background subtraction using frame differences, like `mean filter` as you mentioned. But please keep in mind that it will only detect moving foregrounds, and manually providing threshold is difficult. I suggest you to instead try `Mixture of Gaussian` method, which is more effective, and implemented in OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

To solve you particular problem of joining separate parts, use dilation http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=dilate#dilate