# locating a moved object without using keypoints

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, tracking, object-detection, object-recognition

I am trying to determine the movement and rotation of an object (can be plain-colored, but does not have to be) on a not completely constant background. Here is an example:

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Using keypoints to find the transformation as in the [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/table_of_content_features2d/table_of_content_features2d.html) does not work because the objects I am dealing with do not necessarily provide enough edges for this.
Building the difference image and doing a segmentation there also often fails, because of the changed background. In this example it is not that bad, but there could be changed reflections or slight deformations.

[image: difference image]

Any ideas on how I to find the transformation matrix (affine, with only four degrees of freedom) that maps the object (in this example the blue thing) from one image to the other?

Comment: Perhaps you should try optical flow methods. Then you won't need to compute a transformation. 

The Lucas Kanade method probably won't be able to handle such smooth regions, so you should go for global methods such as Horn-Schunk.

You can also use more elaborate techniques, such as SIFT-Flow.

What do you think of this solution?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried cv.CalcOpticalFlowHS but was unable to find parameters that actually worked for me. SIFT-Flow looks interesting. Do you know an implementation to use with OpenCV?

Comment: I only know of this implementation: 
http://people.csail.mit.edu/celiu/ECCV2008/

Comment: Matlab, oh joy. :D (Yeah, I already found that.) I will check if I can translate something of it or use a faster keypoint descriptor to do something similar.

Comment: Did you develop a solution, Dobi, or is this question still open?

Comment: No real solution yet. I experimented with optical flow but without success. At the moment I am trying so solve this image registration problem with phase correlation in the frequency-domain. Translation only is OK that way, but rotation is more difficult because I need a common rotation center for creating the log-polar image. Are you working on a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use binary threshold on result of images subtraction(as described here - [Foreground Extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367837/foreground-extraction)) - it should delete small changes(which are results of changes in lightning). Before that you may try to use some filter to blur edges, median filter may be a good option(but try different filters too) - try using this technique on both input images and result of images subtraction.

**//edit:**
For determine the transformation you may try to use SURF - http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html
If you don't need to calculate rotation try to use optical flow technique - http://robots.stanford.edu/cs223b05/notes/CS%20223-B%20T1%20stavens_opencv_optical_flow.pdf or much simpler method:
1. Calculate geometrical center(just add positions of all points and divide the result by number of points) of marker contour on first and on second image(name them contour1 and contour2). Alternatively you may calculate center of mass of filled contour - it's up to you.
2. You transformation is: movementVector = centerOfContour2 - centerOfContour1

If the results will be not accurate enough, try to find biggest contour on image and draw this contour on empty image(so you won't have any noises, artifacts etc). Perform all operations on the new image.

Comment: Yeah, blurring before calculating the difference image helps to some degree, even though the results are not perfect. But lets say I would have a quite good contour of the moving objects (in my example here without the overlapping part, because the color is the same there). How can I then determine the transformation?

Comment: Sure, with SURF (SIFT, BRIEF, ORB and so on) it would be easy, but they do not work on many of the objects I deal with, as in the example. And the movement vector alone is not enough. I also need the rotation, but the segmented contours from the difference image are not good enough to use the principal moment of inertia for this. And drawing the segmented contour on a new image does not help if the segmentation is not good in the first place. To exemplify this I choosed the objects to overlap in my example. ;)